# How to write query with multiple models in Django

Tags: django, models

How to write a query for student who logged in(`student = self.request.user.id`) to view his assignments titles (belong to his 
intake)

```
    class intake(models.Model):
    intakecode = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    modules = models.ManyToManyField(Module, through='IntakeDetails')

    class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    primary_key=True)
    intakecode = models.ForeignKey(intake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

student belong to a intake and each intake many modules.

```
    class IntakeDetails(models.Model):
    intake = models.ForeignKey(intake, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecturer = models.ForeignKey(Lecturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     module= models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class AssignAssignment(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    duedate=models.DateField()
intakedetails=models.ForeignKey(IntakeDetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

I tried this one but if there are more than one `intakedetails`, however, it pops up an error.

```
@login_required
class ModelIndexView(ListView):
template_name= 'accounts/students/students.html'
context_object_name= 'students'
def get_queryset(self):
    student = self.request.user.id
    student_det = Student.objects.get(user_id=student)
    assignment=IntakeDetails.objects.get(intake_id=student_det.intakecode)
    queryset=AssignAssignment.objects.filter(intakedetails_id=assignment.id)
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you use `objects.get` there should be only one row matching your query. No row or multiple rows [result in errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get) --`ObjectDoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned` respectively.

You may use this query to get your desired result:

```
AssignAssignment.objects.filter(intakedetails__intake_id=Student.objects.get(user_id=student).intakecode)
```